# openCV, C++ concurrency, windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, opencv

We are building a program that has a server streaming video from a client. We are using C++ in visual studio. Running in debug mode takes away all weird symptoms.

OBS: running in release but turning of optimizations with /0d still gives the symptoms.

Symptoms: While calling imshow("blabla", image); in the server we get the following error: "Unhandled exception at 0x54F26AF8 (opencv_highgui248d.dll) in newCVS2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x69577265."
However if we do a imwrite("example.jpg", otherimage); before we do not get this error. image and otherimage are different images. We have tried stepping through the code, no strange jumps are done that I know of.

In the code below search for imwrite("test.jpg",tmp3) with the code below we will get the error, if imwrite is uncommented we will not. I included all the code for reference.

OBS: imwrite solves the problem it is not the cause of it!
thanks in advance, any comments appreciated.

Example of code:

```
    // newCVS2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>

#include <process.h>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>


#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void streamServer(void* arg);
void  quit(string msg, int retval);
int connect();

//HANDLE hMutex1;
Mat frame;
Mat img;

SOCKET ListenSocket;
SOCKET ClientSocket;
WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int iSendResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
int is_data_ready = 0;

HANDLE hMutex1 = CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE, NULL );

HANDLE syncMutex = CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE, NULL );


void streamServer(void* arg){

    int  imgSize = img.total()*img.elemSize();
    char* sockData = new char[imgSize];
    int  bytes=0;

    int errorMsg = connect();
    if(errorMsg != 0){
        cout << "error on: " << errorMsg;
    }

    SYSTEMTIME before;
    SYSTEMTIME after;

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    memset(sockData, 0x0, sizeof(sockData));
    do {
        GetSystemTime(&before);
        for(int i = 0; i < imgSize; i += iResult){
            iResult = recv(ClientSocket, sockData  + i, imgSize - i, 0);
            if(iResult == -1){
                printf("resv failed");
            }
        }

        GetSystemTime(&after);
        cout << (((after.wSecond * 1000) + after.wMilliseconds) - ((before.wSecond * 1000 ) + before.wMilliseconds)) << " time for recv \n";

        //int ptr = 0;
        GetSystemTime(&before);
        WaitForSingleObject( hMutex1, INFINITE );
                    for(int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++){
                        //row = sockData.part(
                        for(int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++){

                            (img.row(i)).col(j) = (uchar)sockData[((img.cols)*i)+j];
                            //img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = cv::Vec3b((uchar)sockData[ptr+ 0],(uchar)sockData[ptr+1],(uchar)sockData[ptr+2]);
                            //ptr = ptr + 3;
                        }
                    }

        cout << img.rows << " number of rows ";
        GetSystemTime(&after);

        is_data_ready = 1;
        memset(sockData, 0x0, sizeof(sockData));

        ReleaseMutex( hMutex1 );

        cout << (((after.wSecond * 1000) + after.wMilliseconds) - ((before.wSecond * 1000 ) + before.wMilliseconds)) << " time for annoying shit \n";

        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        }


        //Close the connection
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        //Fail during connection
        else  {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
        }

    } while (iResult > 0);

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}

int main()
{
    int width, height;
    width = 640;  
    height = 480; 
    img = Mat::zeros( height,width, CV_8UC1);



    is_data_ready = 0; // not needed



    _beginthread( streamServer, 0, NULL );
    //needed to make sure that server does not close
    while(true){
        WaitForSingleObject( hMutex1, INFINITE );
                if(is_data_ready){

                    cout << img.rows << " number rows before show \n";
                    cout << img.empty() << " empty? \n";



                    WaitForSingleObject( syncMutex, INFINITE );

                    Mat tmp0, tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, tmp4;

                    tmp4 = img;

                    bilateralFilter(img, tmp0, -1, 50, 5); 
                    Canny(tmp0, tmp1, 35, 200, 3); 

                    /*imwrite("test.jpg",tmp3);
                    waitKey(1);*/

                    ReleaseMutex( syncMutex );

                    WaitForSingleObject( syncMutex, INFINITE );

                    imshow("ServerWindow", tmp1);

                    ReleaseMutex( syncMutex );

                    waitKey(1);
                    cout << img.cols << " number cols after show \n";
                    is_data_ready = 0;
                }

        ReleaseMutex( hMutex1 );
        waitKey(1);
    }
    //connect();
    return 0;
}


void  quit(string msg, int retval){

}
int connect(){

    /*WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;*/


    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // No longer need server socket
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
If adding the test if tmp1 is empty as suggested I get another exception:

```
bilateralFilter(img, tmp0, -1, 50, 5); 
                    Canny(tmp0, tmp1, 35, 200, 3); 
                    //ytp = frame;
                    //testImage = frame;

                    imwrite("test.jpg",tmp3);
                    waitKey(1);

                    waitKey(500);
                    ReleaseMutex( syncMutex );

                    WaitForSingleObject( syncMutex, INFINITE );

                    if (tmp1.empty()) { 
                        std::cout << "tmp1 is empty" << std::endl; 
                        break;
                    }
                    imshow("ServerWindow", tmp1);
```

the program now crashes on imwrite and throws the exception:
Unhandled exception at 0x67BDFF1F (msvcr110d.dll) in newCVS2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x67706A2E.

it is making me think that there is some problem accessing the mats

Answer (score 1):

- Check if `tmp1` is not empty, for example

  ```
  if (tmp1.empty) { 
      std::cout << "tmp1 is empty" << std::endl; 
      break;
  }
  ```
- I noticed that OpenCV's `imshow` function is not thread-safe (at least on Windows machine). For example, if I call `imshow` from two different threads my program would crush. The program would also crush if I called `namedWindow()` command in one thread and then `imshow()` command in another thread. So make sure you don't do that. As a side note, it is better to create an output window using `namedWindow("ServerWindow")`, before calling `imshow`. Create this window only once (outside of the `for` loop) and in the same thread where you call `imshow`. This will improve the performance and may fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the good comment.
I tried adding the tmp1.empty line

now the program crashes and gives an exception:
Unhandled exception at 0x67BDFF1F (msvcr110d.dll) in newCVS2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x67706A2E.

The program crashes on the imwrite line. Which is super weird.

I have updated the main post with info

Comment: Furthermore if I actually call:
namedWindow("ServerWindow",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

I get the exception: Unhandled exception at 0x66796AF8 (opencv_highgui248d.dll) in newCVS2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x69577265. On that line

Comment: @Arnagath You may be accessing the data pointed by `tmp1` from more than one thread. It could be that the reason your program works with `imwrite` in it is because `imwrite` accesses the disk and so it takes longer time to execute. During the time `imwrite` is executed, the other thread may finish accessing the shared data (e.g. data pointed to by tmp1), so there is no exception. Try to make access to `Mat` thread safe. Bottom line, make sure that your program is thread safe by protecting shared data from simultaneous access.

Comment: Also be aware that when you assign `Mat image = other_image;`, both `image` and `other_image` are not pointing to the exact same data. So by changing `image`, `other_image` will be changed as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `tmp3` is only initialized, it does not have any data. Trying to write `tmp0` or `tmp1` will work in this code.

Comment: You missunderstood, imwrite does not cause the problem, using imwrite fixes the problem. The reason why we have an empty tmp3 is to reduce the time needed to save the image. The program crashes on imshow only if we DONT have imwrite before.

writing tmp0, tmp1 tmp3 all works fine, it is when I do not write anything.

Haha I see that it is confusing but dont know how to formulate better :P

Comment: Did you try using waitkey(500) in the area where imwrite is used? (keeping imwrite commented out)

Comment: I just tried that, and waitkey(5000) to no avail, still crashes at imshow.

It feels like a concurrency problem even thow I dont see it jumping anywhere while stepping through.